# pass no-ascii characters to the tr() internationalization method of PyQt4 with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, internationalization, pyqt4, decode

Python3, PyQt4 and internationalization.

I want to pass some string containing non-ASCII characters to the `tr()` method of PyQt and I get the following error:

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject
>>> QDialog.tr(QObject(), 'abc')
'abc'
>>> QDialog.tr(QObject(), 'abcγδε')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: function takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given)
>>>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [trUtf8()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#trUtf8). [tr()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#tr) is for ASCII strings. (its signature is `const char * sourceText, ...`)

```
QDialog.trUtf8(QObject(), 'abcγδε')
```